# Were there any other synonyms to "sustainability" before the 80s?

Tags: etymology, history, phrase-requests

[image]

[image]

The German word for *sustainability*, *Nachhaltigkeit*, arose (according to [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nachhaltigkeit)) in the 18th century. Ngrams shows this. I was wondering if the concept of sustainability did not exist before the 1980s? At least in English science, wasn't there a technical term, phrase, whatever to describe this problem?

Does anyone know if there were more common terms/technical phrases and when they arised the first time in English science/books? I need some keywords for a historical search.

Comment: As interesting as those graphs are, it is difficult to get a coherent inference from them, because the frequency of those words, is very dependent on part of speech -and- cultural use. Does the German _Nachhaltigkeit_ have the same connotation as the English _sustainability_ off environmental concerns (sustainability of natural resources and economic growth)? _Sustain_ by itself does not.

Comment: FWIW, Google (books) returns about 263000 results for *long term feasibility*. Google (everything) returns a significantly higher number.

Comment: @mitch ngrams search was done in english (sustain) and german (nachhaltig) books, in dont see how its incoherent. In Wikipedia both terms correlate to each other in ENG/DE. Probably the Club of Rome was one of the first stressing this term and making it more popular, but i would be very surprised if it was not used or there was no common synonym before the 80s. Actually the german term has no connotation, it was created exactly for this context/problem. *sustain* is no noun, i just added it to ngrams as it is the etymological origin

Comment: @Auto: Well, Google Everything includes a much larger database, so one would expect many more results from there for any certain search than from Google Books.

Comment: @drɱ65 imho your question title editing was a bit unlucky, as i want to know, if there were any OTHER terms/synonyms in use, not when sustainability arose, which the first answer is now about. Thats interesting too, but already proven by ngrams

Comment: @Hauser: Sorry for my misunderstanding: how's the edit?

Comment: @Hauser: by "difficult to get a coherent inference', I meant that individual words can have very different frequencies based on so many different reasons. So a simple comparison of graphs is not enough, one needs to look at the data points creating the graphs (at least, or refine the search).

Comment: @Dr M: Of course. But I guess Herr Hauser is more interested in the Books search. I'm *guessing*, because I'm not sure what  *Historical Search*, the last two words in the question, mean.

Comment: @drɱ thx its fine now. I think arguing why a word is not used is hard retrospectively, ngrams does a better job here. And if i have some synonyms i can actually search them in ngrams to see how the use developed vs. each other?

Comment: @Hauser:...(contd) From a superficial look at the data, the primary denotation of 'ability to sustain' is maintained over the course of the entire time range, but it seems that in the steep rise since 1980, the connotation of economic/environmental sustainability is enhanced (even though it sometimes occurs that way before 1980). I don't know of any particular text or event that might have triggered the steep rise  at the beginning of the 80's.

Comment: @mitch ok, thats true, but actually then i would think that *sustainability* gives more hits than *nachhaltigkeit*, as it is ambiguous and a not mainly scientific term. The interesting in the ngrams chart is not the absolute frequency, but the strong rising not before the 1980s? Or do you disagree? This can be no big data error/mistunderstanding imho, im not asking how often the term was used, but when at all

Comment: @Hauser: yes the rapid increase starting in the early 80's is surprising. I would have thought that the concept (and so the word) would have had a steady increase (much less than the exponential we see) starting in the 60's with English books and trends starting from Schumacher's 'Diet for a Small Planet'.

Comment: @Hauser: I [did that](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=tenable%2Cviable%2Csustainable%2Cmaintainable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) with "maintainable", "tenable", and "viable" (the best synonyms I could find).

Comment: Perhaps I'm alone (as others have answered), but I don't know what sense of _sustainability_ you mean. A definition and example sentence in the question would remedy that. (Note there are at least two definitions of _sustainable_ that have to do with ecology: see [Wiktionary's entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sustainable?oldid=14249784) and click the "quotations" down-arrow on the third definition.)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1007/

Answer (score 4):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Sustainability) says sustainability is from 1972, though its root words are much older.

> **sustainable**
>   1610s, "bearable," from ***sustain*** + -***able***. Attested
>   from 1845 in the sense "defensible;" from 1965 with the meaning
>   "capable of being continued at a certain level." *Sustainable growth* is
>   recorded from 1965. Related: *Sustainability* (1972).

---

An article by Nathan Thanki called [*Sustainable: a philological investigation*](http://humjournal.com/article/sustainable) gives some background, here's an excerpt that neatly links *sustainability* with *Nachhaltigkeit*:

> So it is what we are trying to sustain that is usually the meat of
>   arguments about “sustainability”—is it overconsumption,
>   overpopulation, environmental degradation? The term has become
>   synonymous with that “meat” in the past few decades. The Club of Rome,
>   in its 1972 report, “Limits to Growth,” claimed that it was searching
>   for a global equilibrium, “a world system that is: 1. sustainable
>   without sudden and uncontrolled collapse; and 2. capable of satisfying
>   the basic material requirements of all of its people.”  When the World
>   Commission on Environment and Development (aka the Brundtland
>   Commission) concluded with the notion of “sustainable development,”
>   the emergence of the concept we know too well today was fully
>   underway. Since that time, sustainability has come to be almost
>   synonymous with “sustainable development, defined in *Our Common Future*
>   as “development that meets the needs of the present without
>   compromising the ability of future generations to meet their own
>   needs.”
>   ...
>   While the origins of the words association with the environmental seem
>   to lie in the emergence of the environmental movement of the 70s,
>   Ulrich Grober points out a deeper root. In “A conceptual history of
>   ‘sustainable development’ (Nachhaltigkeit),” he argues that the term
>   actually comes from 18th Century forestry (at the time timber was a
>   key resource with an uncertain future). German nobleman and forester
>   Hans Carl von Carlowitz wrote “’daß es eine continuirliche beständige
>   und nachhal–tende Nutzung gebe,’ (that there would be a continuous,
>   steady and *sustained* use).” Sadly, Europe no longer has any primeval
>   forest outside of the Białowieża Forest in Poland and Belarus.So it
>   would appear to me that the quest for “sustainability” is older than
>   we commonly recognise, and, thus, so is our failure to achieve it:
>   marking the failure of civilization.

---

Edit: The 1972 date is surprisingly late, here are some antecedents from [1906](http://books.google.com/books?ei=LjSETu2qF4KEOt-qgdUB&ct=result&id=rLE5AQAAIAAJ&dq=sustainability&q=sustainability#search_anchor) and [1907](http://books.google.com/books?id=OtayAAAAIAAJ&q=sustainability&dq=sustainability&hl=en&ei=LjSETu2qF4KEOt-qgdUB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAjisAg).

Comment: I think the idea that *sustainability* only came to have its current meaning in 1972 is frankly ludicrous. Obviously the need for that meaning has increased dramatically in recent decades, but, for example, [here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=_hEPAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22sustainability%22&hl=en&ei=242DTtWLAcmr8QPFs-UJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22sustainability%22&f=false) a 1951 report from (then Rhodesian, now Zambian) government which specifically mentions the ecological and economic dimensions of the term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: your data about 'sustainability' is corroborated by that for 'sustainable. Etymonline seems to be factually wrong about the shorter word. ngram for sustainable growth[](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sustainable+growth&year_start=1800&year_end=1973&corpus=0&smoothing=3) gives examples of 'sustainable growth from earlier than the 60's.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The 1972 date is surprisingly late, but please check your report again: there's no mention of Rhodesia and it's from Costa Rica in 1993 (you need to be careful with Google Books' OCR). Anyway, here's a [1906](http://books.google.com/books?ei=LjSETu2qF4KEOt-qgdUB&ct=result&id=rLE5AQAAIAAJ&dq=sustainability&q=sustainability#search_anchor) and [1907](http://books.google.com/books?id=OtayAAAAIAAJ&q=sustainability&dq=sustainability&hl=en&ei=LjSETu2qF4KEOt-qgdUB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAjisAg)

Comment: @Hugo,Mitch: Hmm. My original link was indeed mislabelled. Checking a bit more closely I get the impression *sustainable* was originally used in respect of law/debate. After WW1 it started to be used of *economic* development, but I can't actually find anything pre-1972 where it has *ecological* connotations. If no-one else can, I guess I'll delete my first comment, upvotes notwithstanding.

Answer (score 3):

From a cursory perusal of on-line thesauruses, it looks like there are no instances of alternates for the word '[sustainability](http://thesaurus.com/browse/sustainability)'.

For '[sustainable](http://thesaurus.com/browse/sustainable)' there are a number of synonyms, but still none that really match the meaning of 'sustainable'. However, any kind of proposed synonym should work as the beginning of a keyword, historical search. I suggest

- maintainable
- endurable
- supportable
- manageable

in that order of 'closeness'.

Comment: I venture to suggest that prior to the last few decades, the need for any such term was largely unrecognised. Even today there will be huge variations between what different people think are truly *sustainable* practices. That's partly why politicians and admen like these sort of words - they know that nearly everyone thinks they represent "good things", but the words are sufficiently vague that they can be used almost freely without getting tied down by precise definitions and commitments.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, it was once self-identified conservatives who cared about conserving the environment. (The words do not overlap by accident.) A *conservative* approach or a *conservationist* approach was the contemporary equivalent as far as I can tell. The [conservation movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_movement) was a global phenomenon that Wikipedia, at least, traces to seventeenth-century France and Prussia.

Comment: Correct. Conservation is a synonym for sustainability that is no longer in use but certainly was last century. Both these words refer to the desire to maintain our environment for future generations.