# Have any words experienced sustained frequency growth greater than the word "sustainable"?

Tags: historical-change

XKCD comic [1007](http://xkcd.com/1007/), "sustainable", has indicated that the frequency of the word "sustainable" has undergone significant growth. According to [explain XKCD](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1007:_Sustainable), it has gone from 0.000005% in 1960 to approximately 0.003% in 2012 - an increase in almost three orders of magnitude in half a century.

Have any other words experienced a sustained frequency growth greater than that?

Criteria:

- Relative growth, not absolute growth: the word "a" going from 1.4% to 1.5% is a large absolute growth, but very small relative growth.
- A non-trivial frequency at the end of the growth: "aimag" going from essentially zero before 1970 to 0.0000035% in 1999 isn't that significant. An ending frequency of at least 0.0001%, or preferably greater than 0.001%, would be good.
- Having a growth rate (measured over a period of at least two years) greater than that of "sustainable"'s half century average.

Comment: This question was inspired by http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43611/were-there-any-other-synonyms-to-sustainability-before-the-80s

Comment: Yes,  mainstream: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sustainable%2Cmainstream&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csustainable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmainstream%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Try "laptop" or any of a hundred other words that have obtained new meanings in the time period.

Comment: Also *software* and to a much smaller relative degree but higher absolute *identity*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sustainable%2Cmainstream%2Cidentity%2Csoftware&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csustainable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmainstream%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidentity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoftware%3B%2Cc0